# Problem installing apache 2 in ubuntu 14.04: dpkg:- error processing package javascript-common (--configure):

Tags: 14.04, apt, apache2, dpkg

I was trying to reinstall my apache 2 after un-installing it. But on installing it using command-

`sudo apt-get install apache2`

i am getting error-

```
rahul@rahulpc:~$ sudo apt-get install apache2
[sudo] password for rahul: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
apache2 is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libblas3 liblinear-tools liblinear1
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 474 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up javascript-common (11) ...
dpkg: error processing package javascript-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 javascript-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

i think i have removed some essential directories while un-installing apache 2 . Anybody please help me to recover the files and to install apache 2.

Comment: For the javascript-common issue run `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoclean`..now reinstall apache2 with `sudo apt-get --reinstall install apache2`

Comment: Thanks for answer @heemayl, your first command runs fine but on running 2nd command ie reinstalling apache2 it again gives same error.

Comment: @RahulSatal Have you found a solution? I have the same problem. Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove javascript common and reinstall again :

```
sudo apt-get purge javascript-common 

sudo apt-get install javascript-common
```

And then install packages.

Source : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2232128

Comment: Worked for me. Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 3):

i uninstall it , and the dpkg reconfigure

**apt-get --purge remove javascript-common**

**sudo dpkg --configure -a**

if you need it , install it again

**sudo apt-get update**

**sudo apt-get install javascript-common**

Answer (score 2):

My problem was with javascript-common (I use Dedian) not being configured. My solution was to remove it and to install apache2 before installing javascript-common. It seems that javascript-common expects some configuration files to be exitent before being able to configure it.

```
sudo touch /etc/apache2/conf-available/javascript-common.conf

sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Download the javascript-common_11_all.deb package manually and instaled it with

```
dpkg -i  javascript-common_11_all.deb --force-all
```

good luck